# Deezer sdk android : seek with the TrackPlayer class

Tags: android, java-native-interface, audiotrack, deezer

I initialized my TrackPlayer like this :

```
trackPlayer = new TrackPlayer((Application) context.getApplicationContext(), deezerConnect, new WifiAndMobileNetworkStateChecker());
trackPlayer.playTrack(trackId);
```

Then, I want to seek into the track with this code :

```
if (trackPlayer != null && trackPlayer.isAllowedToSeek()) {
trackPlayer.seek(newPositionInMs);
}
```

I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve AudioTrack pointer for getSampleRate()
            at android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_playback_rate(Native Method)
```

If everyone can help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue might happen if you try to seek too soon. When you call playTrack(), the player needs to fetch the requested track information, and download the track, which means that the player might not be initialised yet when you call the seek method.

You might want to wait for the player  to be in the READY or PLAYING state before seeking.

To do so, just add a PlayerStateChangedListener on your player.